# subset $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ question

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors

So the question says: consider the subset $W$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ consisting of all vectors

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
x \\ y \\ z
\end{bmatrix}
\qquad \text{such that } x+y+z \geq -1
$$

Select all statements that are correct:

A. There exists a $3 \times 3$ matrix $B$ whose image is $W$.

B. $W$ is closed under addition.

C. $W$ contains the zero vector.

D. $W$ is closed under scalar multiplication.

E. There exists a 3×3 matrix $A$ whose kernel is $W$.

F. $W$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

So basically, if $W$ is a subspace it has to satisfies B, C, D together. But as a subset, the only statement I can see is correct is C, right? Also, I am not sure if A is correct, but I think F is wrong because a kernel is the subset of the source not the target, right?

Comment: You are correct that only C is true, and basically for the reasons you give.  The image and kernel of a linear transformation are vector spaces, and $W$ is not a subspace as you point out.

Comment: $v=\begin{bmatrix}0\\0\\-1\end{bmatrix}\in W$. But what about $v+v$? $2v$?

Comment: Take the matrix whose all entries are zero. The image of this matrix will be in W surely. Any other non zero matrix wouldnt have this property. Because W contains no subspace.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

B: False: $[0,0,-1] + [0,0,-1] = [0,0,-2] \not \in W$.

C: True

D: False: $2[0,0,-1] = [0,0,-2] \not \in W$.

F: False: requires all B,C,D true

A,E: False as per Callus's comment that the kernel and image of a linear transformation are vector spaces, and $W$ isn't a vector space.